# Use gcc-c++ compiled code from Python

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost

I have a c++ codebase, which has been compiled using g++ make. Now, I want to use the same code from python. I was going through the net, and came across boost.python. Although it tells me how to convert one single c++ code into a python module, but it does not tell me anything about how to use it for code that has got Makefiles, and which is compiled using g++ make. It's a hierarchy of c++ files, each one calling the other, that I want to use in my python code. Can anyone tell me how should I do it?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it stands now, the question is quite vague.  Boost.Python provides the ability to expose C++ to Python; it does not dictate the build tools.